# python script that checks column value in excel sheet and sends mail to that particular person in outlook by the name of distribution list(DL)

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, distribution-list

I want to write a python script that checks a column value in excel sheet and sends mail to that particular person in outlook by the name of distribution list(DL). I am unable to fetch DL with the following code. Please help me on this.

More details:
The sender should be the DL name i.e., DL IQWDL SSDBU NEC Global xyzglobal.abcbu@pqr.com
The receiver should an individual name i.e., rahul.kumar@pqr.com

Code:

```py
    import win32com.client as win32 
    import pandas as pd
    
    #Read the excel file 
    xl = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\rahulk\\Downloads\\corepy\\excel_report.xlsx')
    
    #Select the email addresses from a specific column in the Excel file 
    email_addresses = xl['Email'].tolist()
    
    #Connect to Outlook and get the distribution list your text 
    outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application") 
    dl = outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(win32.constants.olFolderContacts).GetDistributionListFromID("xyzglobal.abcbu@pqr.com")
  
    #Loop through the email addresses and send the email your text
    for email_address in email_addresses: 
        email = outlook.CreateItem(win32.constants.olMailItem)
        email.To = email_address 
        email.Subject = "Email Subject" 
        email.Body = "Email Body" 
        email.SentOnBehalfOfName = dl.DLName 
        email.Send()
    
    #Release the Outlook instance 
    outlook = None
```

Comment: What is not working with the code you have supplied?

Comment: show example of your excel file as well

Comment: There is no such method in the OOM - `GetDistributionListFromID`.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide the `GetDistributionListFromID` method for the `Folder` class. To find an item in the folder you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook Contact items using Restrict method](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/21/outlook-retrieve-contact-items/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext to retrieve Outlook Contact items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/19/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-contacts/)

Be aware, the `To` property expects a semicolon-delimited string list of display names for the `To` recipients for the Outlook item. Otherwise, I'd suggest using the `Recipeints.Add` method for adding recipients. See [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) for more information.